# What is the behavor of pessimistic locking when accessing a belongsTo or other relationship?

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm utilizing [pessimistic locking](https://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/hibernate/manual/index.html#_pessimistic_locking) in my password reset code.

Basically what happens is the user provides a token (that was emailed to them in a prior transaction), then in a service the state is retrieved with `PasswordResetRequest.findByToken(token, [lock: true])`. Some validation happens (was the token valid? did the request expire?), and then the user associated with this reset request is retrieved with `request.user` (a `PasswordResetRequest belongsTo User` relationship). The user's password is then updated, the user is saved, and the `PasswordResetRequest` deleted.

I know that according to the docs, the `PasswordResetRequest` will be locked (and thus a new query will block when retrieving it). But what about the `User` that's associated with it? What happens if I have some other request happening that reads a user by ID, updates, and saves it (say the user was miraculously updating their account at the same time they were resetting their password)?

So my question is, when locking a child that `belongsTo` parent, does the parent get locked as well? If not, how would I achieve this (do I need to perform eager fetching or something)?

I'm also curious about the behavior of other relationships. Is there documentation that talks about all of these?

Answer (score 0):

From my own experience with locking, I would recommend reading some article about DB locking ([DB locks](https://www.brightbox.com/blog/2013/10/31/on-mysql-locks/)) at least it helped me a lot with an understanding of how and why some records are locked and other not.

As for your question, all entries that will be fetched when you already triggered locking will be locked as well. 
So if you do request.user then User instance will be locked as well(by id).

Also if you are not sure that all works well I would recommend making a small test. Insert sleep(2000) (make a delay) in you password reset method (after you 'initialize' user)  and then call another method that will try to update user entry it should fail.